# Is there a way to pass multiple cmd argument on python module shutil.which()

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

Lets say i want to identify the location of multiple executables on powershell, i would use `Get-Command python, git` (`Get-Command` is Unix `which` like command)

Is there any way/workaround to  archive the same thing without looping thorough (passing multiple cmd arguments) with the module `shutil` i.e `shutil.which(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3)`? or is there any other module with that capability ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a loop?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander that is what i am escaping

Comment: oops! another story i forgot to mention, long story short is i am on windows, and the `which` command is just a `function which($name) {
    Get-Command $name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
}` under the hood. so the question would be archiving same thing as `Get-Command` which is a powershell command. Btw i thought linux/unix `which` had the same mechanism